# Data's Effect on Optimization Algorithm running into a Saddle Point

Tags: maximum-likelihood, nonlinear, optimization

I am working with a non-linear model that uses seven independent variables to estimate a Bernoulli probability.

To estimate the parameters of the model, I am optimizing a likelihood function using the `optim` function in R. I have tried several of the optimizing algorithms available in the `optim` function.

The optimizing algorithm is frequently running into saddle points. Mathematically, I understand how increasing the dimensions increases the number of saddle points the optimizing algorithm can run into. I also understand how my non-linear model makes this a non-Convex optimization problem.

What I am trying to obtain is an intuitive understanding of what is it about the nature of the data that could make this model run into a saddle point? Obviously you don't have my data at hand and can't answer specifically, but I want to understand what is it in general that can make a model run into a saddle point for one data set but not another.

Comment: It's just the nature of the geometry of the data set, it has a lot of saddle points. A quick trick to try and avoid getting stuck at a saddle point is to rerun the optimization with a new starting value. However if your data is littered with saddle points this probably won't help.

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to understand is what is it about the data that can cause so many saddle points? Is there some inherent limitation or flaw in the data that causes the parameters to be difficult to estimate? I have a very intuitive understanding on why, for example, multicollinearity causes parameters to be difficult to estimate. I'm hoping to gain something like that here.

Comment: Technical, but may help.http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2572

Comment: It's totally dependent on your likelihood function. Without knowing your likelihood, there's no way anyone can say why the likelihood function is multimodal. In addition, if you're using `optim`, I'm assuming it's a custom likelihood, which increases the odds of there being a bug in the likelihood function code.

Comment: I mention that last bit because many classic log likelihood functions are concave under mild conditions, making optimization much easier. Machine learning researchers seem less concerned with creating convex loss functions than statisticians. I would suggest this is a result of statisticians starting from "given X assumptions of data, what is the *best* estimator?", where as ML researchers tend to approach it as "I want a really good estimator without worrying *too* much about the math". But I digress.

Comment: Since you're interested purely in the 'data' - have you tried looking at adjusted empirical likelihood theory? Might be too off topic, but it might help spark an idea about what you're looking for about the 'nature of the data'. See Chen, et al 'Adjusted Empirical Likelihood and its Properties' - with many examples. http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jhchen/paper/Chen.Variyath.Bovas.pdf